# Remove Special Characters from data in any column with Excel Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro to remove special characters from data that can show up in many difference columns depending on the spreadsheet. I want to highlight the column and remove special characters from the data in that column with the macro. The data can look like this below:

```
AE/ABCD/001234/ABCD
AE/ABCD/001234//ABCD
AE.ABCD.001234.ABCD
AE.ABCD.001234..ABCD
```

Any help is appreciated

I tried this below but I couldn't get it to work and I don't want to create a new column

```
Sub Test()
Dim myString As String
Dim newString As String

myString = "I"

newString = Replace(Replace(myString, ".", " "), "/", " ")



MsgBox newString

End Sub
```

Comment: I would do a search and replace (this can be done with VBA)

Comment: record a macro using find and replace. that's going to be the quickest way to address this.

Comment: `Selection.Replace ".", " "` and `Selection.Replace "/", " "`  those two lines only in a sub that you call after selecting the cells you want to adjust.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Scott Craner's comment, you can replace your string this way:

```
Sub Test()
    
    ' Select the area where you want to replace
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select
    Selection.Replace ".", " "
    Selection.Replace "/", " "


End Sub
```

Also if you want to get the column reference where replacing happened then it is better if you walk through the entire (by two loop) table and reaplce cells one by one. And if the replacing occures you will know which column you are and you can do whatever you want.

```
 Sub Test()
    
    ' Select the area where you want to replace
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select
    Selection.Replace "a", "X"
    Selection.Replace "d", "1"
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
    LastColumn = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Column
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        For j = 1 To LastColumn
            Dim colorColumn As Boolean
            
            If InStr(Cells(i, j), ".") Then
                Selection.Replace ".", " "
                colorColumn = True
            End If
            
            If InStr(Cells(i, j), "/") Then
                Selection.Replace "/", " "
                colorColumn = True
            End If
            
            If colorColumn Then
                ' Do column coloring
            End If
            
            
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```